# Unwanted colored borders around Javax.swing Containers

Tags: java, user-interface

[image: Window titled "ENTER NAME LATER" with two tabs, one titled "How to use" with an arrowed numbered 1 pointing to it, the other titled "START" with an arrow numbered 2 pointing to it; within the pane -- pointed at by arrow 3 -- selected by the "start" tab is a label 4, titled "open directory", and a box, 5, with a "Personal Option" label] In the above screenshot we have a JFrame containing A JTabbedPane which (in Tab2) contains a JButton opening a JMenue.

So I want to change the color of these . JFrame worked all good as you see it is now black. And now with the JTabbed pane starts my first issue.

- Problem 1: As you see (marked with a 1) the tab1 background color is set but there is this white frame around it is there a way to remove that?
- Problem 2: As you see (marked with a 2) a selected tabs background hast this white blueish color ,is there a way to change that `.setForeground(Color c)` doesn't seem to work.
- Next Problem (marked with 3) you see the main body of the JTabbedPane has also a border is there a way to remove that (maybe the same as Problem 1).
- Problem 4 and 5 are the borders around the JButton (marked with 4) and the JMenue (marked with 5) is there a way to remove the borders?

I tried .setForeground on the JTabbedPane.

Comment: You've already found the easy way of changing the colors. The harder (but ultimately better) way is to create or modify the look and feel (disclaimer: I've never cared to get into the L&F stuff myself) `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("fully qualified name of look and feel");`

Comment: A note for the future: A question's title should not just be a description of the question's topic, but a description _of the question itself_. I've attempted to edit towards that end.

Comment: Also, Swing is 25 years old now. It's old and cranky, and not very good at doing things it wasn't made to do. HTML / JavaScript / CSS 3 is so so so much fresher.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you / I‘ll try doing better next time but thank you for editing

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thank you for your answer maybe i‘ll try to make aproject using another language (or multiple ) at a later point,but I fought there maybe would be a simpler option only using java. But thank you for your input

Comment: [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)